# Swift Map an Array of Dictionaries and get the results as Strings not Optionals

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

Is there a way to map an array of dictionaries and return the value of a key as a string and not an optional? This code works but the results are all optionals, not strings.

```
let arrGroupTitles = arrGroups.filter { $0.keys.contains("title") }.map { $0["title"] as? String }
```

Output:

```
[Optional("Q2 2023 Themes and Outcomes"), Optional("Q3 2023 Themes and Outcomes"), Optional("Q4 2023 Themes and Outcomes"), Optional("Backlog Themes and Outcomes")]
```

Comment: `compactMap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop `filter`. And `compactMap` the array. If the key doesn't exist the dictionary will be skipped

```
let arrGroupTitles = arrGroups.compactMap { $0["title"] as? String }
```